# jQuery CDN is not loading on LocalHost

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn

I have a jquery cdn loading from the following:

```
<head>
.
.
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

then in the body I have my source for my script

```
<body>
.
.<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is all on local, but when I view in browser I keep getting the following errors in console:

```
GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I assume this is saying the jQuery function "$..." is undefined because there is an error in GET of the CDN, why would this be happening on local?

Comment: Try seeing what is happening via a debugging too. For instance, if you are using Chrome open your inspector, to to the 'Network' tab, and refresh the page. You will be able to see if your request is failing, etc.

Comment: @NickMitchinson it says status:(failed) & Type:PENDING

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You aren't actually running on localhost (`http://localhost`) but on the local file system (`file:///path/to/whatever.html`). The protocol is copied with the `//` link to `file://ajax.googleapis.com` which of course doesn't exist.

You should set up a server on your computer so that you'd have an *actual* localhost accessed with the http protocol. It would have other benefits as well since browsers act a bit differently also in other regards when the page is loaded directly from the file system.

Comment: Really, you should try to fallback to a file on your own webserver if the CDN call fails. Which will work with `file://` as well, since you just fallback

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing the "//" at the beginning of the "src" attribute and instead using "http://"? It is probably appending "localhost" to the beginning of the URL because of those slashes.

Comment: It would fix the problem but then you'd lose the benefit of using the `//` url (using http or https automatically depending on what the current url is using).

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question in [How to use Bootstrap CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377277/how-to-use-bootstrap-cdn/21318735#21318735) and, as Juhana said, the problem is the missing protocol when loading jQuery.

The protocol-less CDN works when you are using http or https, because browsers will add the prefix to the jQuery URL with it.

But when using a local html file, the missing protocol will be `file:` and browsers will not be able to find jQuery in something like `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js` failing to load it. In that case you must add the protocol manually, which is a pitty if you finally use the page on-line because a protocol-less URL is better and more cache friendly (http://encosia.com/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/).