# Div's Stacking When They're Not Supposed To w/ Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Probably a very simple solution but I starting to work with Bootstrap and I can't figure out why each `div`is stacking instead of inheriting its associated `col` width. (for ex. `.col-md-1` should have a smaller width than `.col-md-6`) Included a JS Fiddle as well.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .row > div {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid white;
    } 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the JS fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ew9L3z35/

Comment: They occupy a different amount of columns based on what you've set them at, but they share the same breakpoint as they are all MD. See your own jsfiddle above 992px.

Comment: Is the syntax I've submitted correct? When I expanded the viewport on jsfiddle they did occupy different amounts of columns, however on my pc they still stack. Not sure why.

Comment: No, the syntax above and in the jsfiddle are just default classes with some styling that would change any behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's not stacking as you say on my end, but I expanded my screen. However keep in mind they will stack at their designated break point. So your example is using `.col-md-*` has a container width of 960px. It can be deceptive on a fiddle or codepen if your output view is small.

Read more about their breakpoints on [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 0):

After searching a little harder it was a simple fix. Just needed to include `http`in the URL that loads both Bootstrap and JQuery files because I'm loading my html from a local file (my computer).

Instead of:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Use:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

You do this for all files being loaded from a CDN. Here's a link to the post I found explaining the problem. [How to use Bootstrap CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377277/how-to-use-bootstrap-cdn) Hope this helps!