# Why does an "http:-less" CDN reference not work when running a standalone html page?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-api, google-chrome-devtools, iis-express

I had this in my main (only) page's head section:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I run this app/site from Visual Studio 2013/local IIS, it references jQuery fine; however, when I try to run it from Windows Explorer by 2-clicking the .html file, the google map won't load, and Chrome Developer Tools, Console window, shows "jQuery not found" errors.

Prepending the "http:" to the CDN reference like so:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...solves the problem. Why?

Comment: It doesn't work when you're not running on an actual webserver, and there are several duplicates as this has been asked a hundred times before. Use the search bar up in the right corner first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery CDN is not loading on LocalHost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795080/jquery-cdn-is-not-loading-on-localhost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the protocol included the browser uses the the protocol of the current page. If you load the page from the file system, in this case it is `file:///`, so you end up looking for something like `file:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`