# Ruby on Rails app Localhost internet connection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new with ruby on rails.
The problem is:

When i tried this:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it doesn't work
but when I include directly the file in my project it works:

```
<script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am running my app on `http://localhost:3000` but it seems the application cannot access to internet.
How can I fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery CDN is not loading on LocalHost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795080/jquery-cdn-is-not-loading-on-localhost)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `http`

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```