# Jquery not rendering

Tags: jquery

I have inserted a horizontal timeline from www.codyhouse.co for a client into their Squarespace account. No on my end the timeline looks like this:
[timeline my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90TOK.jpg)

however, when the client logs into their account on Squarespace and looks at the same page this is what it looks like for them:
[timeline client view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO5lo.jpg)

some of the code:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var timelines = $('.cd-horizontal-timeline'),
        eventsMinDistance = 60;

    (timelines.length > 0) && initTimeline(timelines);

    function initTimeline(timelines) {
        timelines.each(function(){
            var timeline = $(this),
                timelineComponents = {};
            //cache timeline components 
            timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'] = timeline.find('.events-wrapper');
            timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'] = timelineComponents['timelineWrapper'].children('.events');
            timelineComponents['fillingLine'] = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].children('.filling-line');
            timelineComponents['timelineEvents'] = timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a');
            timelineComponents['timelineDates'] = parseDate(timelineComponents['timelineEvents']);
            timelineComponents['eventsMinLapse'] = minLapse(timelineComponents['timelineDates']);
            timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'] = timeline.find('.cd-timeline-navigation');
            timelineComponents['eventsContent'] = timeline.children('.events-content');
```

Not sure why it is doing this. Can someone please, please help!!

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: A little bit of code would be good. Just from looking at these pictures, nobodoy can probaly help you here.

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet showing how you have included jquery library ??

Comment: are you trying in your local , if so use complete CDN URL - http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: @NagaSaiA OP is using the full URL. You don't need to give it the protocol. The browser can work that out based on the protocol of your domain.

Comment: @putvande, running on local file system ,cometimes may cause an issue as OP mentioned - file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js  which is wrong.... link for reference-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795080/jquery-cdn-is-not-loading-on-localhost

Comment: Ah yeah.. im used to running everything over my localhost when working on my laptop. You're right.

Comment: No local being used I am working directly from squarespace. if I remove cdnjs.cloudflare.com from my jquery script my code no longer works at all