# My jQuery code is not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning jQuery, after I add the code, those functions that I have set are not running at all. Noted that, around 2 weeks ago, they run properly, so no errors in linking files in HTML. But now, I open the html file in Chrome and it is not working at all.

Furthermore, when it was running (2 weeks ago), I tried to hook the 3.2.1 version but it did not run at all. When I tried the older version, which is 2.1.4, it worked. Pls help

This is my code:

1. HTML:

.

```
<html>
    <head>            
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="box">a box</div>

        <div id="navArrows">
            <button id="left" class="navigationArrow">&larr;</button>
            <button id="up" class="navigationArrow">&uarr;</button>
            <button id="right" class="navigationArrow">&rarr;</button>
            <button id="down" class="navigationArrow">&darr;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Load the CDN version first -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Load the local version incase the CDN fail -->
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js.jquery-2.1.4.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <!-- Hook in the script.js file -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

2. This is my script.js file that I hooked in:

.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    // Move the box left and increase the fontSize 2px each click
    $('#left').click(function() {
        $('.box').animate({
            left: "-=40px",
            fontSize: "+=2px"
        }, function() {
            // animation is complete

        });
    });

    $('#up').click(function() {
        $('.box').animate({
            top: "-=40px",
            opacity: '+=0.1'
        }, function() {
            // animation is complete

        });
    });

    $('#right').click(function() {
        $('.box').animate({
            left:'+=40px',
            fontSize: '-=2px'
        },function() {

        });
    });

    $('#down').click(function() {
        $('.box').animate({
            top:'+=40px',
            opacity: '-=0.1'
        },function() {

        });
    });
```

3. This is my css code

.

```
#navArrows {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    background: #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.navigationArrow {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background: white;
    color: #222;
}

#up {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

#left, #right {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
}

#right {
    right: 20px;
    left: inherit;
}

#down {
    bottom: 20px;
    top: inherit;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #a7f;
    color: white;
    border: solid 4px #a1f;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    opacity: 0.5;

    position: relative;            
}
```

The css code are type correctly with # and ".", not like the way it present here. I tried but can't make it correctly

Comment: You code works fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/rp77c4ne/. Note that only the left and right buttons work due to the lack of your CSS rules. Check the console for errors.

Comment: Yes, this code runs. It's simply a matter of CSS. Try adding `style="position:absolute;"` to your box div.

Comment: any error on console?

Comment: i tried with  3.2.1 its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your CDN import to

```
<!-- Load the CDN version first -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

You can find the solution here : [jQuery CDN is not loading on LocalHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795080/jquery-cdn-is-not-loading-on-localhost)

Comment: It worked after I add "http:" as you told me. Furthermore, what is the different between open the html file by double clicking it and open via local host like XAMPP? People told me that I should open via XAMPP since it is a server, more practical for debug and see its function, right?

Answer (score 0):

Checked and it works fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/3naqL5wa/

The problem is with "up" and "down" buttons. Your elements has no css attribute "position: absolute;" so top and left doesn't work for them.

```
.box{
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please change the CDN version src attribute to an absolute URL:
2. Should incase you are not connected to the Internet,  the local jQuery version loading is good. But on a live server, just remove it.
3. On your Chrome browser, enter `Ctrl+shift+I` to open browser console for debugging. On the console write: jQuery, if undefined is displayed then you know jQuery is not loaded yet, so your code won't run.