# JS and Bootstrap work in Codepen but not when opened locally

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, codepen

Here is my codepen:
https://codepen.io/ldrumsl/pen/ZxdZwa

Here is the JS:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
```

Here is the downloaded index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>A Pen by  L</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"
integrity="sha256-8oQ1OnzE2X9v4gpRVRMb1DWHoPHJilbur1LP9ykQ9H0="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap- 
theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script 
src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> . 
</script>

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' 
href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrapdatetimepicker/ 
a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap- 
datetimepicker.css'>



</head>

<body>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20vh">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center" style="height:4em"></div>

        <div class="col-12 text-center" style="font-size: 4em;">
          REQUEST EDIT
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 text-center" style="height:4em"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col- form-label-lg">Start Date & Time</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">End Date & Time</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Notes / Reason</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>

<div class="row" style="height: 3rem;"></div>

    <div class="row" style="height: 3rem;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block" style="width: 50%; margin-left: 25%;background-color: grey;">LOGIN</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js'> . 
</script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js'></script>


<script  src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

The above link works just as I would like.  However, when I export the files and open it locally, I get something that looks like:

[Image of local code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEPrW.png)

Does anyone know how to get it so that my code works locally?  I exported the file directly from codepen and have not changed anything.

Comment: well you probably are not including something right. impossible to tell.

Comment: Please include the relevant portions of your HTML (<head> especially) in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery CDN is not loading on LocalHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795080/jquery-cdn-is-not-loading-on-localhost)

Comment: Running locally means off the file protocol or a local server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change these lines in your local html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

`https:` are forgotten in stylesheet urls.

Comment: // is valid protocol for urls unless OP is running off the file protocol than that is not good.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it!